# How to get JaCoCo coverage while running JQF+Zest maven plugin

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, fuzzing

I'm trying to customize the interaction between JaCoCo and JQF+Zest to more accurately see what code lines the fuzzer is working with.

What I've tried:

1. This command (0% coverage):

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:/usr/local/lib/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/here/be/execfile/test.exec" mvn jqf:fuzz -Dclass=full.ClassName -Dmethod=methodName -Dtime=1m
```

2. This commands (0% coverage in the report again):

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:/usr/local/lib/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/here/be/execfile/newtest.exec"
```

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=full.ClassName
```

Then I run at the same time:

```
mvn jqf:fuzz -Dclass=full.ClassName -Dmethod=methodName -Dtime=1m
mvn verify
```

And after that:

```
java -jar /usr/local/lib/jacoco/lib/jacococli.jar report /here/be/execfile/newtest.exec --classfiles /path/to/classfiles --sourcefiles /path/to/src --name test2 --html /path/to/report
```

3. And this (doesn't create any `.exec` files)

```
mvn jqf:fuzz -Dclass=full.ClassName -Dmethod=methodName -Djacocoagent="/usr/local/lib/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar" -Djacocodestfile="/here/be/jacoco.exec"
```

Can you please help me and point out what exactly I am doing wrong? Or maybe I should try something else